# Is there any way to disable new tab on ANDROID browser e.g. chrome, firefox, etc

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, nfc

I'm finding the solution to solve my problem

My project is about reading NFC tag with android device. For everytime I tap NFC tag with my android device. It always open new tab in chrome application. I need it loads new page in currently page or set limit of new tabs for browser (e.g. 10 tabs)

Is there any way to fix my problem ?

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, please post your code.

Comment: If it's not a programming question, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic